# Does not contain a definition for 'NewRow' and no extension method 'NewRow' accepting a first argument of type 'Systems.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

Tags: c#

```
  private void Agregar()
    {

        var rowsChecked = this.DataKitchenArea.AsEnumerable().Where(r => Convert.ToBoolean(r["Sel"]));



        foreach (DataRow rowOrigen in rowsChecked)
        {
            DataRow rowDestino = this.dataGridView1.NewRow();
            rowDestino["Sel"] = false;
            rowDestino["Id"] = rowOrigen["Id"];
            rowDestino["Nombre"] = rowOrigen["Nombre"];
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowDestino);
        }
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataGridView1;
    }
```

La función principal del boton es que agregue a otro grid los filas del checkbox seleccionados

Mi pregunta es que reemplaza el NewRow o que hay que agregarle.

Comment: @AlejandroOlivares las preguntas que estás haciendo son muy similares entre ellas (no se puede mover los elementos de un grid a otro al pulsar un botón). Parecen la misma (o ediciones dentro de la misma) tras avanzar un poco. ¿Cómo se difiere esta pregunta de, por ejemplo, la que se indica como duplicada? El código parece el mismo (salvo una variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `NewRow()` es un metodo de `DataTable` no del `DataGridView`, por lo que deberias usar

```
private void Agregar()
{
    var dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;

    var rowsChecked = DataKitchenArea.AsEnumerable().Where(r => Convert.ToBoolean(r["Sel"]));

    foreach (DataRow rowOrigen in rowsChecked)
    {
        DataRow rowDestino = dt.NewRow();
        rowDestino["Sel"] = false;
        rowDestino["Id"] = rowOrigen["Id"];
        rowDestino["Nombre"] = rowOrigen["Nombre"];
        dt.Rows.Add(rowDestino);
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Si el `dataGridView1` no tiene un DataSource entonces el DataTable deberias crearle la estructura de columnas

Comment: `private void DataTableGrid1()
        { 
            this.DataGridArea = new DataTable();
            this.DataGridArea.Columns.Add("Sel", typeof(bool));
            this.DataGridArea.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            this.DataGridArea.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
        
        
        }`


Hice esto pero no me funciona o a que te refieres me puedes guiar